# How to print a '+' between values and a'=" at the end before the result?

Tags: python

If the user input of the following code is 5 for example. Then the output I get is 3+33+333+3333+33333+37035. How can I have my output be 3+33+333+3333+33333=37035.

I've tried sep, end, but can't seem to get it to print the + as a separator and the = at the end before the result (=370350).

```
n = int(input('Enter a positive integer: '))
sequence_number=3
sums = 0

for i in range(n):
    print(sequence_number, end='+')  with + between each
    sums = sums+sequence_number  # this will add the numbers
    sequence_number = sequence_number * 10 + 3
print(sums)
```

If you have a better way to write this code im all ears!

Comment: Print a backspace and an equal sign before printing the sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution:

```
n = int(input('Enter a positive integer: '))
sequence_number = 3
sums = sequence_number

print(sequence_number, end='')

for i in range(1, n):
    print(f'+{sequence_number}', end='')
    sums += sequence_number
    sequence_number = sequence_number * 10 + 3

print(f'={sums}')
```

Another option:

```
n = int(input('Enter a positive integer: '))
sequence_number = 3
sums = 0

for i in range(n):
    print(sequence_number, end=('+' if i != n-1 else '='))
    sums += sequence_number
    sequence_number = sequence_number * 10 + 3

print(sums)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Check if this is the last iteration, and use a space instead of `+` if it is:

```
for i in range(n):
    if i == n-1: end_char = ' '
    else: end_char = '+'
    print(sequence_number, end=end_char)
    ...
```

2. Append all numbers to a list, and then join them with `+` *outside* the for loop:

```
lhs = []
for i in range(n):
    lhs.append(sequence_number)
    ...

print("+".join(lhs), f"= {sums}")
```

Comment: Great solution! But the second one has O(n) space complexity, in general such things should not be encouraged in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 1):

It'd actually be easier to keep your `sequence_number` as a string for repetition:

```
limit = 5
digit = '3'
sequence = [digit * count for count in range(1, limit+1)]
# ['3', '33', '333', '3333', '33333']
total = sum(map(int, sequence))
# 37035
print(f'{"+".join(sequence)}={total}')
# 3+33+333+3333+33333=37035
```

Some `print` statements omitted for brevity.

Comment: Love this solution. But at the same time it's really useless to memorize every single string (just to print it in the end). The space complexity becomes O(n)

Comment: @RiccardoBucco Agreed, but this is a toy problem so optimization seems like overkill. It'd be easy enough to replace the reified list with a generator expression if space was a real concern.

Comment: It's gonna be O(n) regardless because the string is buffered by `print()`.

Comment: @Samwise and at the point where the memory size of that string starts to affect anything, printing to console will likely also be a bottleneck even if you stream it instead of building a string. None of this matters.

Comment: Yup, there's a reason `print` buffers each line of output instead of flushing each character.  :P

Comment: @Samwise Thanks for your comment, I was not aware of how `print` works!

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension and string operations:

```
lst = [str(sequence_number)*(i+1) for i in range(n)]

>>> "=".join(["+".join(lst),str(sum(map(int,lst)))])
'3+33+333+3333+33333=37035'
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `join` and f-strings to build the actual string you want to print is almost always a better option than messing around with the `print` parameters IMO; if nothing else, it makes it easier to reuse the string if you ever need to do something other than print it.

Some other answers have shown how to do this by building a list; I'll show a way to do it with inline generator expressions.  Assigning the things you'll be using more than once (namely the stringified `sequence_number` and the `range` you need to iterate over) to short variable names makes it possible to express it very compactly:

```
n = range(1, int(input('Enter a positive integer: '))+1)
s = "3"

print(f"{'+'.join(s*i for i in n)}={sum(int(s*i) for i in n)}")
```